# Выборка данных за месяц в MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
select t1._Fld7641, t1._Fld7643, t2._Description, t1._Fld7647
from dbo._InfoRg7639 as t1 
inner join dbo._Reference5145 as t2
on t1._Fld7640RRef = t2._IDRRef
```

В таблице `t1` есть поле `_Fld7641` даты и времени. Таким образом, если выполнить данный запрос, мы получим данные из двух таблиц за все время.

Kак выгрузить данные только за текущий месяц?

Comment: `where поле-с-датой between дата-начала-месяца and дата-окончания`

Comment: инструкция beetween полная аналогия, >= & <=, в таком случае существует вероятность получения события из конечного дня, что нежелательно. Поэтому для поиска по дате лучше использовать >= и <.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare 
@startdate datetime = 'дата начала периода', 
@enddate datetime= 'дата конца периода'  

select t1._Fld7641, t1._Fld7643, t2._Description, t1._Fld7647
from dbo._InfoRg7639 as t1 
inner join dbo._Reference5145 as t2
on t1._Fld7640RRef = t2._IDRRef
where date >= @startdate and < @enddate
```

Comment: предлагаю все же добавить пояснение по используемым переменным в запросе

Comment: благодарю, господа! согласен, по поводу пояснения)

Comment: переменные начала и конца периода и их объявление declare 
_@startdate_ datetime = 'дата начала периода',
_@enddate_ datetime= 'дата конца периода'

Answer (score 1):

Для MSSQL (начиная с версии 2012) данные за текущий месяц можно получить так:

```
select t1._Fld7641, t1._Fld7643, t2._Description, t1._Fld7647
from dbo._InfoRg7639 as t1 
inner join dbo._Reference5145 as t2
on t1._Fld7640RRef = t2._IDRRef
where t1._Fld7641 between dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,-1)) 
and dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```